# GWT 2.8.1 Compiling Error Check that your classpath includes all required source roots

Tags: gwt, libgdx

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'generated://5D5A9B253D17A16EBB484765B24CB357/com/badlogic/gwtref/client/IReflectionCacheAppXAGenerated.java'
  [ERROR] Line 7: Too many constants, the constant pool for IReflectionCacheAppXAGenerated would exceed 65536 entries
  See snapshot: C:\Users\LAPTOP\AppData\Local\Temp\com.badlogic.gwtref.client.IReflectionCacheAppXAGenerated4262133575954183763.java
Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.badlogic.gwtref.client.IReflectionCacheAppXAGenerated'
  [ERROR] Errors in 'generated://5D5A9B253D17A16EBB484765B24CB357/com/badlogic/gwtref/client/IReflectionCacheAppXAGenerated.java'
     [ERROR] Line 7: Too many constants, the constant pool for IReflectionCacheAppXAGenerated would exceed 65536 entries 
[ERROR] Hint: Check that the type name 'com.badlogic.gwtref.client.IReflectionCacheAppXAGenerated' is really what you meant
[ERROR] Hint: Check that your classpath includes all required source roots
[ERROR] Errors in 'sa/com/doit/appx/gwtref/super/com/badlogic/gwtref/client/ReflectionCache.java'
  [ERROR] Line 133: Rebind result 'com.badlogic.gwtref.client.IReflectionCacheAppXAGenerated' could not be found
```

i use gwt version 2.8.1 i tried version 2.8.2 but same error

AppxReflect.gwt.xml
`

```
<generate-with class="com.badlogic.gwtref.gen.ReflectionCacheAppXAGenerator">
    <when-type-assignable class="com.badlogic.gwtref.client.IReflectionCacheAppXA" />
</generate-with>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

This is trouble with GWT version 2.10.0.

Try go to html folder into file build.gradle and change gwtVersion to 2.8.2.